# Using a component selector into other component in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I need to add Slider Component to the Home Page Component.

The Slider Component is

slider.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

slider.component.html

```html
<div class="container-image-slider">
         <img id="img1">
          <img id="img2">
          <img id="img3">
  </div>
```

The Home Component
home.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

home.component.html

```
<app-slider></app-slider>
```

The issue here is it gives error

```html
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-slider' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-slider' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-slider' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<app-slider></app-slider>"): ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@0:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34621)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34596)
    at eval (compiler.js:34497)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34497)
    at eval (compiler.js:34367)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
```

Comment: You've to declare the component in the AppModule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import the component in your app.module.ts:

```
import { AppSliderComponent } from 'pathToComponent';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppSliderComponent
]
```

Answer (score 0):

please import this component on app.module.ts file
Expample:-
import { SliderComponent } from './SliderComponent .component';
and add SlinderCompoent in decalartion prpery array
Example
declarations: [
    SlinderCompoent
  ]